# Emacs-like kill ring in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'm struggling to have in vs code the same behaviour of emacs. There are several extensions available notably [emacs-keymap-improved](https://github.com/rkwan94/vscode-emacs), but I can't make ctrl-y work (the yank, i.e.: paste from the kill ring).

How can I debug what is going on? there are other packages that provide emacs-like  keybindings and I failed with all of them as far as ctrl-y is concerned.

I also deleted my ~/.vscode directory as a way to disable all extensions and try just that one.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take another look at emacs-keymap-improved. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> works as expected for me with VS Code 1.23.1 for Mac.  If you're still having problems, note that the author recently enabled the issue tracker on the Github repo.